# In Java, multiple threads want to manipulate one object, how to get one manipulate that and the others wait until the work is done?

Tags: java, multithreading

My problem is a little complicated:
I have a concurrent map, the threads want to visit and update the map, if two thread want to fetch the same entry of the map, one should first get the map, update it, and the other should wait until the entry has been updated successfully and then fetch the entry.
My original thought is that: I can use another concurrent map, same key with the targeting map and use a latch as its value.
My code is like:

```
private final ConcurrentMap<Long, List<RowKeyMap>> targetmap;    
private final ConcurrentMap<Long, CountDownLatch> helpermap;   
long keyMillis; //key


CountDownLatch restoreLatch = helpermap.get(keyMillis);

    if (restoreLatch != null) {
      try {
        restoreLatch.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted trying to get " + keyMillis);
      }
    }

    List<RowKeyMap> restoredata = targetmap.get(keyMillis);

    if (restoredata == null) {
      //find the entry should be restored, put a latch into the helpermap and restore it 
      restoreLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
      CountDownLatch existingLatch = helpermap.putIfAbsent(keyMillis, restoreLatch);

      if (existingLatch == null) {
        microshards = new ArrayList<>(count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            microshards.add(new RowKeyMap(some parameters));
        }
        List<RowKeyMap> existing = targetmap.putIfAbsent(keyMillis, microshards);

        if (existing == null) {
           {do actual restore job here}
        } else {
           microshards = existing;
        }
        restoreLatch.countDown();
        restoresByDate.remove(keyMillis);
      } else {
        // Lost the race, wait for the restore task is complete and get the new restoredata
        try {
          existingLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted trying to get " + keyMillis);
        }
        {get the new restoredata}
      }
    }
```

But the current version has a bug:

- Thread A executes through first line, gets null for restoreLatch
- Thread B wakes up and executes through first line, also gets null for
  restoreLatch
- Thread B continues on to following lines, sees existingLatch is null
- Thread B continues, puts a created-but-not-yet-restored-into list
  into restoredata
- Thread A wakes up and executes through, get the
  created-but-not-yet-restored-into list from restoredata

Anyone has any ideas to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I have also think about locks, but the map has many entries, if threads are visiting different entries, I hope all of them can do the job. If I have a lock for some parts of my code, the other threads can't fetch data even if they want a different entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you want is a lock per each map entry. I'm not sure a `CountDownLatch` is ideal here, because it cannot be re-used, and creating a new one each time complicates your problem.

But your basic problem is that you are not preventing the race condition for the lock itself.

In order to do that, you must first ensure that a lock object for the entry exists, and that if two threads go to the same entry, *they will get the same lock*.

You can do this by first creating a lock object, then use `putIfAbsent` to put it in the lock map:

```
Object entryLock = new Object();
Object returnedLock = helpermap.putIfAbsent( keyMillis, entryLock );
entryLock = returnedLock == null ? entryLock : returnedLock;
```

What this does is ensure that any two threads that are trying to access the same entry (`keyMillis`) will get the same lock instance. If thread A is the first to run the `putIfAbsent` line, then the new object it created in the first line is going to be the one to be placed in the helper map, and it's going to get `null` back, which means it will also use the object it just placed in the map - `entryLock`. Thread B then comes along and create its own `entryLock`. But when it tries the `putIfAbsent` line, there is already an object mapped to `keyMillis`, `returnedLock`, and that's the object it will use (in this case, the original new lock it created will be discarded to the garbage collection).

So whichever order thy get to the `putIfAbsent` line, they will be using the same lock instance. Now the next step is:

- Lock the lock.
- Run your processing of the data in the targetMap, creating it if it doesn't exist, updating it if it does, etc. All this time, other threads for this particular `keyMillis` are waiting, but threads with other `keyMillis` don't.
- Unlock the lock. One of the other threads that wait for this `keyMillis` entry will now lock the lock.

To do this is pretty simple:

```
synchronized(entryLock) {
   // All operations on the particular entry
}
```

If you need fancier lock facilities then use `ReentrantLock` or a `CyclicBarrier`. A `CountDownLatch` will need to be replaced with a new one to be usable, and that would defeat the arrangement above, which pretty much relies on the lock object being the same for all threads.

Comment: should it be synchronized(entryLock) ? Got a little confused

Comment: @Eleanor Oh, yes. Sorry, fixed.

Comment: Hi, still a little confused about: should I use helpermap.remove(keyMillis, entryLock) after the sync part? As time goes by the helpermap may have too many entries, but i'm not sure if i remove it, whether it will affect other threads.

Comment: You really shouldn't remove the lock from the map unless you are sure more threads will be looking for the key or are in the process of working with the key.

Comment: OK, but is there any point when you know for certain that the current thread is the last one working on a given key?

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is a little complicated...

Uh oh, I've got bad news for you.  If you think *that* problem is complicated....  You actually have identified the simplest problem in multi-threaded program.  It's called *mutual exclusion*.

You can do it like this in Java:

```
final Object lock = new Object();

synchronized (lock) {
    // some protected statements
}

synchronized (lock) {
    // some more protected statements
}
```

The JVM guarantees that no more than one thread can be in a `synchronized(foo)` block for the same object `foo` at the same time.

Comment: My problem is that the map has many entries, if threads are visiting different entries, I hope all of them can do the job. If I have a lock for some parts of my code, the other threads can't fetch data even if they want a different entry.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you want only one thread at a time to operate on the `Map` (probably a good idea), then you can achieve that by wrapping `synchronized(lock) { ... }` around each different place where the map is used.  The `lock` can be _any_ object, even the `Map` itself.  Just make sure that it is always the _same_ object.

Comment: Actually I want multiple threads to operate on the Map at the same time if they have different keys.

Comment: So, perhaps what you want is `synchronized(key) { ... }`, which will allow two different threads to execute the block at the same time if they are working on different keys, but not if they want to work on the same key.

Answer (score 1):

use the synchronized either at the method declaration or inside a block of code.

see here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 0):

Use objects that implement the `Lock` interface. Java has several of these objects by default that you can use. [Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html) is a tutorial that explains what locks are and how to use them.

Comment: The `Lock` interface is more powerful than Java's `synchronized(...)` blocks.  Also more dangerous.  Noobs probably should know about both since they are likely to encounter both.